# how can i return Boolean value on popup confirmation button click in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

when I call this.AlertProvider.presentConfirm() then an ionic popup confirmation display on click confirm button i want to return true/false

```
presentConfirm() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Confirm Activate',
      message: 'Do you want to Disable',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Confirm',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('submit clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
}
var confirm_value = this.AlertProvider.presentConfirm();
alert(confirm_value);
```

Comment: Which version of ionic does the code use?

Comment: In JavaScript, to return values, functions need to use [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statements. Otherwise the function returns a value of [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).